Doesn't this make brahman limited?
If I am brahman, the unchanging reality, the absolute truth and I am the one without a second then why does this world appears to exist?
Now one may give an analogy of snake and rope to answer this. But the problem with analogies of these kinds is that an error(that there is a snake instead of rope) is made because of the limitation of the instrument through which the observation was made. Because our eyes can't see very clearly in the dark and the fact that our brain has evolved in such a way to assume the worst to protect ourselves, we make such errors. They are all limitations of the instrument of knowledge.
But brahman is supposed to be limitless. If brahman is limitless why does this universe appears to it in the first place? Why can't brahman just directly "see" the truth?

Nirguna Brahman does not 'see' the universe, is not aware of the universe - (Gaudapada's Karika I.12 of the Mandukya Upanishad, translator Swami Nikhilananda). It is only those who are within causality that are aware of causality. Asking 'why' can only be asked within the confines of causality. Brahman is beyond causality.
And verse I.17:

If the phenomenal universe were real, then certainly it would disappear. The universe of duality [which is cognized] is mere illusion (maya); Non-duality is the Supreme Reality.
and Nikhilananda's footnotes:
If etc: The disappearance of an object can be asserted only when such an object is taken to be real. But the phenomenal universe, being maya, does not possess reality. Therefore one cannot speak of its disppearance. Only those who believe the phenomenal universe really exists speak of its disappearance.
The Universe etc: According to Non-dualistic vedanta the phenomenal universe is neother real nor unreal; its nature is inscrutable to the finite mind. This is what is meant by maya. The universe is certainly not real; for it undergoes change and is not perceived at all in deep sleep or in the experience of non-dual samadhi. Again, the universe cannot be unreal, in the sense that the son of a barren woman is unreal; for it is perceived to exist. Therefore Vedanta describes the universe as maya, of which neither origination nor dissolution can be predicted.

Swami Vivekananda says (Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, vol.7):

For this reason, nescience [maya] has no absolute reality. You can call nescience neither real nor unreal; "Neither real, nor unreal, nor a mixture of both". About a thing that is thus proved to be false, neither question nor answer is of any significance. Moreover, any question on such a thing is unreasonable.

Perception is the Knower, the Atman.'You' are the Atman. You perceive Yourself now. Your perception of Yourself is distorted by Maya. You are perceiving Yourself, but it is distorted. When you break through the veil of Maya, You will no longer perceive or have awareness of the universe. Realize Yourself...
